# Saxon parsed XSL stylesheet cannot access remote resources

Tags: xslt, http-status-code-403, saxon

Trying to parse an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet with Saxon HE, getting the following error:

```
Error on line 44 column 168 
  XTSE0165: I/O error reported by XML parser processing
  http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/inc/mimeType.xsl: Server returned HTTP response code:
  403 for URL: http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/inc/mimeType.xsl
```

This stylesheet contains a handful of remote resources it attempts to retrieve:

```
<xsl:include href="http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/inc/dcmiType.xsl"/>
<xsl:include href="http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/inc/mimeType.xsl"/>
<xsl:include href="http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/inc/csdgm.xsl"/>
<xsl:include href="http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/inc/forms.xsl"/>
<xsl:include href="http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/inc/iso3166-1.xsl"/>
<xsl:include href="http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/inc/iso639-2.xsl"/>
```

However, I have confirmed that all the links are valid and be retrieved via a browser or curl.  Additionally, when I serve those files on `localhost`, and change the `<xsl:include>` accordingly, I do not get the 403 error.

My question, is there some kind Saxon or Java setting that is preventing Saxon HE from accessing resources not on `localhost`?

Many thanks in advance for any suggestions.

**Update:** I'm using [pyjxslt](https://github.com/cts2/pyjxslt) as a server to perform the Saxon transformations, running at `localhost:6767`.

Comment: You have tagged your question with the error code you get and if you read the description of that tag it clearly says " the server refuses to respond to the request" so it is not a problem of Saxon but rather one of the server refusing to serve the stylesheet.

Comment: Yes, but for all those URLs listed in the stylesheet, they *are* accessible through browser or curl, without any 403 errors.  So why would Saxon -- or perhaps more accurately, the XSLT stylesheet -- requesting the documents result in a 403?

Comment: I don't know, it could for instance be because of user agent settings that are different between a browser and the Java net APIs. You could sniff the HTTP request/responses between your machine and the server and try to compare the ones from the browser to the ones done by Saxon.

Comment: That's where I was going next, thanks for the sanity check.  Must be something in the request.

Comment: FWIW I get the same effect: I can access these URLs using Safari, but not using the one-line query doc('http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/inc/dcmiType.xsl') run from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this using the doc() function from the XQuery command line, using "Charles" to monitor the HTTP traffic.

The detailed HTTP response says that the site is using Cloudflare to restrict access, and that it has refused access "based on your browser's signature".

So unless you can insert some kind of proxy to change the browser signature in the request, or persuade the owners of the site that their security policy makes no sense, you may be out of luck.

One thing I notice is that Safari includes "accept application/xml" in the HTTP request header, and Java does not. It's possible that the site has somehow been configured not to serve XML unless the request header says it will accept XML. I haven't seen this happen before, but it's something to investigate.

Incidentally, by default Saxon doesn't call the Java APIs directly to get a document; if you use the standard (default) URIResolver then this creates an InputSource object wrapping the requested URL, and the InputSource is passed to the XML parser which then calls Java to fetch the resource. I don't know which Java APIs the XML parser is actually using. But if you can find a way that works, you could bypass this by writing a URIResolver that configures an HTTP request and gets an InputStream directly.

Comment: This is most helpful, thanks.  I hadn't had the chance to observe the request headers, but the `accept application/xml` would suggest that prompting the right content negotiation is what this server requires.  Thinking either looking into writing a URIResolver, or even just incorporating a small proxy server that sends the appropriate XML headers, will work for this application that requires XSLT transformations.  Thanks again.